# Google Cloud scheduler Java job containerized with Selenium

Tags: java, docker, selenium, google-cloud-platform, quarkus

I've got a Java code to perform some interactions with web pages and used Selenium for it.
Now I'd like to get this code executed every hours and I've thought it's a great occasion to discover the cloud world.

I've created an account on Google Cloud.
Because my app need to have a driver to use Selenium (gecko driver for Firefox), I'll have to create an docker image to set everything it need inside it.

In Google Cloud services, there is the "Cloud Scheduler" which can allow me to run a code when I want to.

But here are my questions :

- What kind of target should I configure (HTTP, Pub/Sub, HTTP App Engine)?
- Because I'm not using the Google Cloud Functions, my container will always be up, it doesn't seems as a great idea for a pricing reason? I would have like to have my container up only the time of the execution.
- Also I was thinking to use Quarkus framework to wrap my application since I've since it was made for the cloud and very quick to start, is that the best option for me?

I'll be very glade if someone can help me to see this a little better. I'm not a total beginner I work as a Java / JavaScript developer for 5 years now and dockerized some application but everything about the cloud is a big piece, not easy to know where to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you:

- are using docker images
- run your workload occasionally
- aren't willing to use Cloud Function

==> **Cloud Run** is your best bet. Here is Google Cloud Run Quick start : https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/prebuilt-deploy

Keep in mind that your containerised application needs to be listening to HTTP requests so take a look at Cloud Run *[Container runtime contract](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/container-contract)*

Finally you can indeed trigger Cloud Run from  Cloud Scheduler, and here a detailed documentation on how to do it https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/triggering/using-scheduler

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to create an image of my application and test it in local before to push it to Google Cloud and select it from Cloud Run. Having a container always up, with a quarkus application is not an issue, isn't it going to cost me a lot ? I think I'll try and because I've got 300$ for three months I'll see the results.

Comment: You have generous free tier as always with google cloud services, so you 300$ dollars wont be used. More details on cloud pricing here https://cloud.google.com/run/pricing

Answer (score 1):

As @MBHAPhoenix says, Cloud Run is your best option. You can then trigger the job from Cloud Scheduler. We have this exact scenario currently running for one of our projects but our container is Python. We wrote an article about it [here](https://nocommandline.com/blog/step-by-step-guide-to-deploying-your-app-to-google-cloud-run/)

You should note that to trigger your Cloud Run job from Cloud Scheduler, you'll have to 'secure it'. This means means you won't be able to just type the URL in a web browser. A service account will be responsible for running the Cloud Run job and you'll then need to grant your Cloud Scheduler service access to this service account so it can invoke the Cloud Run Job. I've been meaning to put up a post about the exact steps for doing this (will try to get it done this weekend).

In terms of cost, we have this snippet from our article

...*Cloud Run only runs when it receives an HTTP request. It plays dead and comes alive to execute your code when an HTTP request comes in. When it is done executing the request, it goes 'dead' again till the next request comes in. This means you're not paying for time spent idling i.e. when it is not doing anything*.....